# Complex Self-Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, self-join

I have a problem with a view, I'm working with Sql Server.
I have a table like this:

```
+-------+------+
| Start | End  |
+-------+------+
|     1 | Null |
|     3 | 4    |
|     6 | 9    |
+-------+------+
```

This table represents a series of timeframe, if End is Null this means that it has not finished, but there may be short breaks (3-4 and 6-9), I would like to create a view that will show all the timeframes like this:

```
+-------+------+
| Start | End  |
+-------+------+
|     1 | 3    |
|     3 | 4    |
|     4 | 6    |
|     6 | 9    |
|     9 | Null |
+-------+------+
```

I can't find a solution. I tried more than than an hour with no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `union all` with `lead()`:

```
select start, lead(start) over (order by start)
from ((select t.start as start from likethis t
      ) union all
      (select t.end from likethis t
      )
     ) t
where start is not null
order by start;
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can use `cross apply`:

```
with t as (
      select t.start as start from likethis t
      union all
      select t.end from likethis t
     )
select t.start, tnext.start 
from t cross apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.start > t.start
      order by t2.start desc
     ) tnext
order by start;
```

Comment: `WHERE Start IS NOT NULL` else we will get the `NULL` value from `END` column in result

Comment: There is a problem, in the production server the sql version is 2008...

Is there some alternative to lead?